# Django usage of ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I have this micro ticket "system"

\\models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    creator_adress = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ticket_waiting = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ticket_solved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reopened_counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

Until now, only one message (when the user opens the ticket) can be sent by the user, which will be forwarded to the admin. But the admin and the user can't write any other messages back and forth under the ticket yet.

If you use a new model for this, which is connected to every single ticket like so?

```
class TicketMessages(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    admin_message = models.TextField()
    user_message = models.TextField()
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Thank you very much :>

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this efficiently with the following method,

create a model for ticket message :-

```
class TicketMessages(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField() #this will be the message
    message_by = # you can use a foreign key or a choices option to select between the admin or user
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey("self") # if this is a reply to existing message
```

This is kind of an good and efficient solutions as per my understanding of your problem .... if you need something else or something more, let me know I'd love to help you.

Thanks !

Comment: Thank you, I already tried something https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70865999/django-cant-save-a-form-to-specific-model

That is my post and i messed it up